# Find the pattern of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions, pattern-recognition

I am given the series $$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1\cdot 8}{6\cdot 10} + \frac{1\cdot 8\cdot 15}{6\cdot 10\cdot 14}$$

I am asked to find a formula for this series $a_n$

So I have found that the last fraction multiplied at $nth$ term is $\frac{(1+7(n-1))}{(6+4(n-1))}$

But I am stuck, unsure how to proceed after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try recursion.

You know that each term (after the first term, of course) is simply the previous term multiplied by a varying constant that relates to $n$.

So try something like:

$$a_1 = \frac{1}{6} $$ and $$a_n = a_{n-1} \cdot \frac{1+7(n-1)}{6+4(n-1)}.$$

Comment: (+1) This is extremely useful for applying the ratio test.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? The question asks me to use ratio test, which is why I am trying to find a formula for $a_n$ . I tried to substitute $a_n = \frac{1+7n}{6+4n} \cdot \frac{1+7(n-1)}{6+4(n-1)}$ and use ratio test to cancel out the $nth$ term. But I did not succeed

Comment: Not to hijack robjohn's comment, but think about what you need to do to apply the ratio test, and think about how the $n+1^{th}$ term relates to the $n^{th}$ term in the recursive definition

Comment: During ratio test, all the previous terms should cancel out, leaving only $\frac{(1+7(n-1))}{(6+4(n-1))}$. But this is incorrect?

Comment: That looks spot on, except maybe an index or two being off. What's the next step of the ratio test?

Comment: The limit goes to $\frac{7}{4}$, which is correct as the final answer. But the formula is wrong (There is an intermediate step for the formula). I verified this multiple times.

Comment: If you're trying to type this into a computer, try seeing where I started my recursive definition (which is where you started your recursive definition), and where the computer asks you to start your terms, i.e. is your first term your first term ($a_1$) or is your first term your zero-th term ($a_0$)? And how does that affect your recursive formula?

Comment: The question did not specify the starting point, I will have to try. Thank you